# Python web server does not close stdin in CGI script

Tags: python, post, webserver, cgi

A Python simple webserver is started to serve a POST request.

In the CGI script, reading the request body from stdin hangs.

CGI script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo
cat
exit 0
```

It should simply copy the received body to the output web page. Content-type can be left away, does not change anything.

Starting the web server:

```
$ python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

HTTP request:

```
$ curl localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hello -d "key=value"
```

The request hangs and does not terminate.

With a C program (in exchange to the bash script) i checked that "key=value" is received and further reading is hanging, no EOF is received.

Can the python web server somehow be told to send a EOF after putting the body into the CGI script's stdin?